# mysql connect to remote DB

Tags: mysql

I have a cluster witht a database saved on the master. I would like to connect from the workers to the db.

Here what I did on the master:

```
bomble@master:~$ mysql -u root
mysql>  GRANT ALL ON ChemAlive_DB.* TO root@worker1 ;
```

And on the worker1:

```
bomble@worker1:~$mysql -u root  -h xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

I also tried:

bomble@worker1:~$ mysql -u bomble  -h xx.xx.xxx.xxx

In both case I get:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx'
>   (110)

Ping is working but not telnet:

```
bomble@worker1:~$ ping xx.xx.xxx.xxx
PING xx.xx.xxx.xxx (xx.xx.xxx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.04 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.254: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.939 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.254: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.887 ms

--- xx.xx.xxx.xxx ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.887/0.956/1.044/0.074 ms
bomble@worker1:~$ telnet xx.xx.xxx.xxx
Trying xx.xx.xxx.xxx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: It looks like the port mysql uses is not open on both the machines (firewall)
check [mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html) and [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/260239/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-through-port-3306)

Comment: I agree but I don't understand how to open them

Comment: Are you running windows or linux?

Comment: To open [port 3306](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-18-allow-mysql-server-incoming-request.html) (assuming you are using default config). 
[Check if anything is listening on a port](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Security_Guide/s1-server-ports.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your config, maybe bind-address = 127.0.0.1 is not commented
If you use Debian or Ubuntu run the command vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf and
comment bind-address = 127.0.0.1 using the # symbol, after restart your mysql server once.
If is not helped, check skip-external-locking (for remote connected must be not commented)

Comment: I look in vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf the 'bind-address = 127.0.0.1' is not there at all. Same for skip-external-locking. I am on ubuntu.

Comment: you can send me your my.cnf file? Look carefully, if not both parametersб see `[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user  = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port  = 3306
basedir  = /usr
datadir  = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir  = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
#skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address  = 127.0.0.1
#`

Comment: section [mysqld] line must be #bind-address = 127.0.0.1 and skip-external-locking (second if only try to connect to mysql from remote app or other site)

Comment: Here it is: # The MySQL database server configuration file.
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

Comment: I look in /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf there is just: [mysql] written but in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf there is much more things! I'm having a look

Comment: That's what it! Thanks